# How to detect browser scroll reached to bottom of each element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 div element with different height. Example:

```
<body>
    <div id="d1" style="height: 800px; float: left; width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="d2" style="height: 920px; float: left; width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="d3" style="height: 876px; float: left; width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="d4" style="height: 1200px; float: left; width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="d5" style="height: 1105px; float: left; width:100%;"></div>
</body>
```

Minimal height of div is equal window height.

How can I detect when user scroll to bottom of each element?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery solution (in scroll event listener)

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#d5').offset().top + $('#d5').height() - winHeight) {
    // scrolled to the bottom of d5 div.
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#d4').offset().top + $('#d4').height() - winHeight) {
    // scrolled to the bottom of d4 div.
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#d3').offset().top + $('#d3').height() - winHeight) {
    // scrolled to the bottom of d3 div.
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#d2').offset().top + $('#d2').height() - winHeight) {
    // scrolled to the bottom of d2 div.
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#d1').offset().top + $('#d1').height() - winHeight) {
    // scrolled to the bottom of d1 div.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess [jquery.viewport](https://github.com/xobotyi/jquery.viewport) could solve your problem.